# What is the reason my action bar color si not changed?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the following lines of code in my styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        //Other three color items
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/colorLightGreen</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this is how the color is defined in the colors.xml:

```
<color name="colorLightGreen">#008000</color>
```

And the color doesn't change. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: did you set the theme style in manifest.xml

Comment: @SauravKumar Yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean...
@color/colorDarkGreen